# How to get rid of "Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = ..."

Tags: java, logging, apache-kafka, avro, slf4j

I am sending Apache Avro formatted messages to a Kafka broker instance via the following code:

```
        ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(kafkaTopic.getTopicName(), null, null,
                avroConverter.getSchemaId().toString(), convertRecordToByteArray(kafkaRecordToSend));

        String avroSchemaName = null;

        // some of my AVRO schemas are unions, some are simple:
        if (_avroSchema.getTypes().size() == 1) {
            avroSchemaName = _avroSchema.getTypes().get(0).getName();
        } else if (_avroSchema.getTypes().size() == 2) {
            avroSchemaName = _avroSchema.getTypes().get(1).getName();
        }

        // some custom header items...
        producerRecord.headers().add(MessageHeaders.MESSAGE_ID.getText(), messageID.getBytes());
        producerRecord.headers().add(MessageHeaders.AVRO_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SUBJECT.getText(),
                avroSchemaName.getBytes());
        producerRecord.headers().add(MessageHeaders.AVRO_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCHEMA_ID.getText(),
                avroConverter.getSchemaId().toString().getBytes());
        if (multiline) {
            producerRecord.headers().add(MessageHeaders.AVRO_SCHEMA_MULTILINE_RECORD_NAME.getText(),
                    MULTILINE_RECORD_NAME.getBytes());
        }

        try {
            Future<RecordMetadata> result = kafkaProducer.send(producerRecord);
            RecordMetadata sendResult = result.get();
            MessageLogger.logResourceBundleMessage(_messages, "JAPCTOAVROKAFKAPRODUCER:DEBUG0002",
                    sendResult.offset());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MessageLogger.logError(e);
            throw e;
        }
```

The code works fine, the messages end up in Kafka and are processed to end up in an InfluxDB. The problem is that every send operation produces a lot of INFO messages (client ID number is an example):

- [Producer clientId=producer-27902] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 10000 ms.
- [Producer clientId=producer-27902] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
- Kafka startTimeMs: ...
- Kafka commitId: ...
- [Producer clientId=producer-27902] Cluster ID:

which Spam our Graylog.

I use similar code to send *String* formatted messages. This code is executed without producing INFO messages...

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> recordToSend = new ProducerRecord<>(queueName, messageText);
    recordToSend.headers().add("messageID", messageID.getBytes());

    Future<RecordMetadata> result = _producerConnection.send(recordToSend);
```

I know that the INFO message are logged from class `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer`. I need to get rid of these messages, but I do not have access to the logging.mxl defining the logger properties for Graylog.

Is there a way to get rid of these messages via POM-entries or programatically?

Comment: Those logs are coming from log4j, before they arrive in graylog, so have you tried using your own log4j configuration?

Comment: No, I didn’t. The message spam was due to a bug / design flaw of mine. See my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the code behavior was a design flaw:
The code in the post above was placed in a method which was called for sending the message to Kafka. The `KafkaProducer` class was instantiated in that method and each time when the method was called. Surprisingly, `KafkaProducer` issues the `Closing the KafkaProducer with timeoutMillis =` not only at an explicit close() by the calling code, but as well when the strong reference to the instance is lost ( in my case when the code leaves the method), In the latter case, the `timeoutMillis` is set to 9223372036854775807 (largest long number).

To get rid of the many messages, I moved the `KafkaProducer` instantiation out of the method and made the instance variable a class attribute and I do not call an explicit `close()` after the `send(...)` any more.

Furthermore I changed the instance of my class instantiating `KafkaProducer` to a strong referencing class member.

By doing so, I get some messages by the `KafkaProducer` at instantiation, then there is silence.

Comment: Have you an example of what changes you made to the code to get this working?